# access after press button

Tags: forms, ms-access, user-interface, vba

In access I have the 'main' form and one button that opens another access form in pop-up window to fill the date. User enters the date and comment there and press 'save' button. I want that this date immediately will be shown in the main form.

```
The code to open new form:
Private Sub btn_P_Phase_Click()
Id = Me.txt_ID.Value
If Me.txt_ID > 0 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_P_Phase", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal
End If
End Sub
```

And the code in the additional form to save dates and comments:

```
Private Sub btn_Save_Click()
Dim int_msg As Integer
Dim cCont As Control
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Me.txt_ID.SetFocus
Id = Me.txt_ID.Value
P_comment = Me.txt_P_comment.Value
P_Date = Me.txt_P_phase_date.Value
CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE CI SET Status = 'Plan', P_Date ='" & P_Date & "', P_comment = '" & P_comment & "' WHERE ID = " & Id & ";"), dbSeeChanges
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_P_Phase", acSaveYes
End Sub
```

I've tried to write something like that in my main form:

```
Private Sub frm_P_Phase_AfterUpdate()
Me.txt_P_Dates.Value = Forms!frm_P_Phase!txt_P_phase_date
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRefreshPage
End Sub
```

Comment: Solved. I created event on Form_Close.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Created new event on closing pop-up form to save data.

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
Forms!frm_Kaizen_Cards!txt_P_Dates.Value = Forms!frm_P_Phase!txt_P_phase_date.Value
End Sub
```